# list() method in API causing TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in unit test

Tags: python, list, unit-testing, twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on code that retrieves information from Twilio's Flow system through their API. That part of the code functions fine, but when I try to mock it for unit testing, it's throwing an error from the mocked api response.

Here is the code being tested:

```
from twilio.rest import Client


class FlowChecker:

    def __init__(self, twilio_sid, twilio_auth_token):
        self.twilio_SID = twilio_sid
        self.twilio_auth_token = twilio_auth_token
        self.client = Client(self.twilio_SID, self.twilio_auth_token)

        self.calls = self.client.calls.list()
        self.flows = self.client.studio.v2.flows

    def get_active_executions(self):
        active_executions = []
        for flow in self.flows.list():
            executions = self.client.studio.v2.flows(flow.sid).executions.list()
            for execution in executions:
                if execution._properties['status'] != 'ended':
                    active_executions.append({'flow_sid': flow.sid, 'execution': execution})
```

And here is my unit test code that's throwing the error:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from flows.twilio_flows import FlowChecker

class FlowCheckerTest(unittest.TestCase):


    @patch('flows.twilio_flows.Client')
    def test_get_active_flows(self, mock_client):
        flow_checker = FlowChecker('fake_sid', 'fake_auth_token')
        mock_call = Mock()
        mock_flow = Mock()
        mock_flow.sid = 0
        mock_execution = Mock()
        mock_execution._properties = {'status': 'ended'}
        mock_client.calls.list().return_value = [mock_call]
        mock_client.studio.v2.flows = [mock_flow]
        mock_client.studio.v2.flows(mock_flow.sid).executions.list().return_value = [mock_execution]
        self.assertEqual(flow_checker.get_active_executions(), [])
```

And here is the error traceback:

```
Ran 2 tests in 0.045s

FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Devon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1369, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
  File "C:\Users\Devon\PycharmProjects\Day_35\tests\twilio_flows_test'.py", line 19, in test_get_active_flows_when_empty
    mock_client.studio.v2.flows(mock_flow.sid).executions.list().return_value = [mock_execution]
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable


Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see, "mock_client.calls.list().return_value = [mock_call]" doesn't throw any errors during **init**, and the first code block runs fine. It's only the mocked executions.list() that's throwing the error in the test.

Can anyone clear this up?

Thank you!

I've tried researching this specific issue and was unable to find information addressing it. It's a very specific deeply nested function in a vendor supplied client that I need to test, so I don't know what to try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with `.list()`, it's with `.flows()`.

```
mock_client.studio.v2.flows = [mock_flow]
mock_client.studio.v2.flows(mock_flow.sid).executions.list().return_value = [mock_execution]
```

You assign `.flows` to be a list, and then you try to call it like a function, which causes the error.

I think maybe you intended to say `.flows[mock_flow.sid]` instead of `.flows(mock_flow.sid)`?

Although even that doesn't make sense.  `.flows` is a one-element list, so you would use `.flows[0]` to access the first (and only) item.